# df.columns giving first row as result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a model summary dataframe that looks like this,
[image]

When I check the column names, I'm getting the values of the first row as the column names. I haven't been able to figure out why

```
print(df.columns)

Float64Index([  0.05082849514894247,    1.0521424302777098,
                0.01622518786759765,  0.019027711286054842,
                0.08262927901183009,     1.019209891842941,
                 1.0861390793499808,    3.1326907006389133,
              0.0017321186522948114,     9.173246524797108],
             dtype='float64', name='cumsum_failures')
```

Comment: What you are showing looks like the output of `df.loc['cumsum_failures']` to me. Can you tell what is the output of `df.columns.tolist()`?

Comment: `df.columns.to_list()` gives the numeric values of the first row

Comment: I think the best is post complete code here.